# CodeIgniter removes session after browser restart

Tags: codeigniter

I have this controller, which loges user with facebook credentials.

```
public function Facebook() {
    $fb_data = $this->session->userdata('fb_data'); 
    // This array contains all the user FB information

    $data['fb_data'] = $fb_data;
    $fb = $data['fb_data']['me']['id'];

    $userdata = $this->user_model->getID($fb);

    $userID = $userdata['0']['id'];
    $userNick = $userdata['0']['nick'];

    $session_array = array(
        'id' => $userID,
        'userNick' => $userNick
    );

    $this->session->set_userdata('user_data',$session_array);
    $user = $this->session->userdata('user_data');

    print_r($this->session->all_userdata());

    //print_r($user);

    if($user['id'] && $user['userNick']) {
        redirect('/');
    }
}
```

It works well, but session is removed after browser restarts. There aren't any cookies created.

Session Config:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

Comment: How to force CI to store sessions.

Comment: apart from fb session data create some sample session like $this->session->set_userdata('sample','abc'); and try to echo it. if it works then it is fault with fb session else you know

Comment: Have you checked your local time? It may cause your cookie to expire (losing all the session data with it). Try checking the cookie with Firebug (or similar) before and after closing the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

In application/config/config.php:

```
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Can you post your session settings?

Comment: `$config['sess_cookie_name']  = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']  = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']  = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;`